# Take value from intent activity -android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to show edit text from ExplicitlyLoadedActivity in ActivityLoaderActivity.
ActivityLoaderActivity

```
package course.labs.intentslab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityLoaderActivity extends Activity {

static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

// For use with app chooser
static private final String CHOOSER_TEXT = "Load " + URL + " with:";

// TextView that displays user-entered text from ExplicitlyLoadedActivity runs
private TextView mUserTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader_activity);

    // Get reference to the textView
    mUserTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Declare and setup Explicit Activation button
    Button explicitActivationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.explicit_activation_button);
    explicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call startExplicitActivation() when pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startExplicitActivation();

        }
    });

    // Declare and setup Implicit Activation button
    Button implicitActivationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.implicit_activation_button);
    implicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call startImplicitActivation() when pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startImplicitActivation();

        }
    });

}


// Start the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity

private void startExplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered startExplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a new intent to launch the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent (ActivityLoaderActivity.this,ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);


    // TODO - Start an Activity using that intent and the request code defined above

    startActivity (explicitIntent); 

}

// Start a Browser Activity to view a web page or its URL

private void startImplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL
    // (HINT:  second parameter uses Uri.parse())

    Intent baseIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(URL));

    // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
    // will carry out the baseIntent
    // (HINT: Use the Intent class' createChooser() method)
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent,CHOOSER_TEXT);


    Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());


    // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent

    startActivity (chooserIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text

        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String input = data.getStringExtra("BAG"); 
                mUserTextView.setText(input);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

'

ExplicityLoadedActivity

```
 package course.labs.intentslab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ExplicitlyLoadedActivity extends Activity {

static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

private EditText mEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.explicitly_loaded_activity);

    // Get a reference to the EditText field
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    // Declare and setup "Enter" button
    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call enterClicked() when pressed

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            enterClicked();

        }
    });

}

// Sets result to send back to calling Activity and finishes

private void enterClicked() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

    // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
    String givenText = mEditText.getText().toString();
    // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
    Intent editText = new Intent();
    editText.putExtra("BAG" ,givenText);
    // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK , editText);
    // TODO - Finish the Activity
    finish();
}
}
```

I read a lot of posts on Stackoverflow but doesn't work for me, the text not appear.
I try many variants inclusive without last two lines of code from ActivityLoaderActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of these two lines is not clear in case you want to stay in ActivityLoaderActivity. Just remove them and you'll be fine. This is given that the rest of your code is correct of course.

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class); 
    startActivityForResult( myIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE );
```

Alternatively, if you indeed want to restart your ActivityLoaderActivity, you should pass "BAG" extra parameter in the new intent and read it in ActivityLoaderActivity.onCreate():

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class); 
myIntent.putExtra("BAG", input);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE );
```

Make sure to declare String input; outside if statements too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried again whitout these two lines.Dosen't work. I tried whithout if's conditions, same result.

Comment: Now is all code. Can you look to startImplicitActivation. The same didn't work.